# Bash - Swap Values in Column

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I have some CSV/tabular data in a file, like so:

```
1,7,3,2
8,3,8,0
4,9,5,3
8,5,7,3
5,6,1,9
```

(They're not always numbers, just random comma-separated values. Single-digit numbers are easier for an example, though.)

I want to shuffle a random 40% of any of the columns. As an example, say the 3rd one. So perhaps 3 and 1 get swapped with each other. Now the third column is:

```
1 << Came from the last position
8
5
7
3 << Came from the first position
```

I am trying to do this in place in a file from within a `bash` script that I am working on, and I am not having much luck. I keep wandering down some pretty crazy and fruitless `grep` rabbit holes that leave me thinking that I'm going the wrong way (the constant failure is what's tipping me off).

I tagged this question with a litany of things because I'm not entirely sure which tool(s) I should even be using for this.

**Edit:** I'm probably going to end up accepting Rubens' answer, however wacky it is, because it directly contains the swapping concept (which I guess I could have emphasized more in the original question), and it allows me to specify a percentage of the column for swapping. It also happens to work, which is always a plus.

For someone who doesn't need this, and just wants a basic shuffle, Jim Garrison's answer also works (I tested it).

A word of warning, however, on Rubens' solution. I took this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
  delim = (i != NF) ? "," : "";
  ...
}
printf "\n";
```

removed the `printf "\n";` and moved the newline character up like this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
  delim = (i != NF) ? "," : "\n";
  ...
}
```

because just having `""` on the else case was causing `awk` to write broken characters at the end of each line (`\00`). At one point, it even managed to replace my entire file with Chinese characters. Although, honestly, this probably involved me doing something extra stupid on top of this problem.

Comment: randomization is not the strength of text processing tools like `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: You want to select 40% of the columns and completely shuffle those, or select one (or more) column and shuffle 40% of its rows?

Comment: The latter (40% of the rows in one column).

Comment: In addition to shuffling not being a strong point, in-place editing is completely and totally impossible using any of the tagged utilities. An external tool would be required -- and the standard ones are very poor. You need a real language.

Comment: Is usage of sed/awk allowed?

Comment: @ormaaj fyi you can do "in place editing" with sed, awk, or bash. Consider `sed -i 's/foo/bar/' file` for example.

Comment: "In-place" editing just means the details of the temporary file are handled for you. Either way, this task requires keeping the entire file in memory, making changes that could involve every line, then writing it back out. `sed` and `awk` are designed for processing line-by-line, without needing to remember every line preceding the current line.

Comment: @EdMorton Awk and Bash certainly can't. IIRC the gawk maintainer specifically didn't want to include an in-place option because it just isn't the tool for the job. Bash can't lseek, which makes it pretty impossible. The best you can do in Bash is tricks like opening an FD read/write, using `read -N` to seek to the right, and re-opening the FD with `/dev/fd/n` to rewind. Really the only shell that has the necessary primitives for that kind of file operation is ksh93 ( using `<#(())`, `<<#`, `>;` etc), and it's quite painful even then.

Comment: @ormaaj - to be clear, we're not talking about real "in place" editing (which bash CAN do, by the way - see the answers to my recent question on the subject in comp.unix.shell) we're talking about someone calling a tool to operate on an input file and once the tool is done running the input file has changed. From a users perspective it's functionally equivalent to true "in-place" editing and any of the tools I mentioned can do that. Aside: gawk will be getting a specific in-place edit option `gawk -iinplace`, functionally equivalent to `sed -i`, in an upcoming release.

Comment: @EdMorton That would be sort of nice. At least awk provides a safe way of injecting shell variables. `sed -i` is just very inadequate. I lean toward using Python (like the `mmap` module and nice abstractions like memoryview) or vim script instead, until maybe someday somebody writes and standardizes a halfway decent non-interactive editor. Though I'll stand by my comment about Bash, even with temporary files. It's been a long time since I've seen an interesting new file manipulation technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Algorithm**:

- create a vector with `n` pairs, from `1` to `number of lines`, and the respective value in the line (for the selected column), and then sort it randomly;
- find how many lines should be randomized: `num_random = percentage * num_lines / 100`;
- select the first `num_random` entries from your randomized vector;
- you may sort the selected lines randomly, but it should be already randomly sorted;
- printing output:

  ```
  i = 0
  for num_line, value in column; do
      if num_line not in random_vector:
          print value; # printing non-randomized value
      else:
          print random_vector[i]; # randomized entry
          i++;
  done
  ```

**Implementation**:

```
#! /bin/bash

infile=$1
col=$2
n_lines=$(wc -l < ${infile})
prob=$(bc <<< "$3 * ${n_lines} / 100")

# Selected lines
tmp=$(tempfile)
paste -d ',' <(seq 1 ${n_lines}) <(cut -d ',' -f ${col} ${infile}) \
    | sort -R | head -n ${prob} > ${tmp}

# Rewriting file
awk -v "col=$col" -F "," '
(NR == FNR) {id[$1] = $2; next}
(FNR == 1) {
    i = c = 1;
    for (v in id) {value[i] = id[v]; ++i;}
}
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        delim = (i != NF) ? "," : "";
        if (i != col) {printf "%s%c", $i, delim; continue;}
        if (FNR in id) {printf "%s%c", value[c], delim; c++;}
        else {printf "%s%c", $i, delim;}
    }
    printf "\n";
}
' ${tmp} ${infile}

rm ${tmp}
```

In case you want a close approach to *in-placement*, you may pipe the output *back* to the input file, using [sponge](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge).

**Execution**:

To execute, simply use:

```
$ ./script.sh <inpath> <column> <percentage>
```

As in:

```
$ ./script.sh infile 3 40
1,7,3,2
8,3,8,0
4,9,1,3
8,5,7,3
5,6,5,9
```

**Conclusion**:

This allows you to select the column, randomly sort a percentage of entries in that column, and *replace* the new column in the original file.

This script goes as proof like no other, not only that shell scripting is extremely entertaining, but that there are cases where it should definitely be used **not**. (:

Answer (score 4):

This will work for a specifically designated column, but should be enough to point you in the right direction.  This works on modern bash shells including Cygwin:

```
paste -d, <(cut -d, -f1-2 test.dat) <(cut -d, -f3 test.dat|shuf) <(cut -d, -f4- test.dat)
```

The operative feature is "[process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)".

The `paste` command joins files horizontally, and the three pieces are split from the original file via `cut`, with the second piece (the column to be randomized) run through the `shuf` command to reorder the lines. Here's the output from running it a couple of times:

```
$ cat test.dat
1,7,3,2
8,3,8,0
4,9,5,3
8,5,7,3
5,6,1,9

$ paste -d, <(cut -d, -f1-2 test.dat) <(cut -d, -f3 test.dat|shuf) <(cut -d, -f4- test.dat)
1,7,1,2
8,3,8,0
4,9,7,3
8,5,3,3
5,6,5,9

$ paste -d, <(cut -d, -f1-2 test.dat) <(cut -d, -f3 test.dat|shuf) <(cut -d, -f4- test.dat)
1,7,8,2
8,3,1,0
4,9,3,3
8,5,7,3
5,6,5,9
```

Comment: +1 `shuf` probably needs to be replaced with a custom shuffler to handle the 40% constraint, but otherwise nice (assuming a fixed number of columns).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a 2-pass approach that starts by getting a count of the number of lines and read the file into an array, then use awk's rand() function to generate random numbers to identify the lines you'll change and then rand() again to determine which pairs of those lines you will swap and then swap the array elements before printing. Something like this PSEUDO-CODE, rough algorithm:

```
awk -F, -v pct=40 -v col=3 '
NR == FNR {
    array[++totNumLines] = $0
    next
}

FNR == 1{
    pctNumLines = totNumLines * pct / 100

    srand()

    for (i=1; i<=(pctNumLines / 2); i++) {
        oldLineNr = rand() * some factor to produce a line number that's in the 1 to totNumLines range but is not already recorded as processed in the "swapped" array.
        newLineNr = ditto plus must not equal oldLineNr

        swap field $col between array[oldLineNr] and array[newLineNr]

        swapped[oldLineNr]
        swapped[newLineNr]
    }
    next
}

{ print array[FNR] }

' "$file" "$file" > tmp &&
mv tmp "$file"
```